# Wait for the first thread to finish before running other threads in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8

From my main flow I want to do some tasks in parallel. Say I have 4 tasks that I want to execute in a separate flow, but in those 4 tasks, 1st task needs to be completed before I can run other tasks in parallel.

I thinks my code works as per my requirement, but is there a better approach?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("In main");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        executor.submit(() -> {
            runParalleltasks();
        });

        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Exiting main");
    }

    private static void runParalleltasks() {
        System.out.println("Running parallel tasks");
        doTask1();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        executor.submit(() -> {
            doTask2();
        });
        executor.submit(() -> {
            doTask3();
                });
        executor.submit(() -> {
            doTask4();
        });

        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Exiting parallel tasks");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have the single thread executor?

Comment: @matt Because I want to execute my 4 tasks in a separate flow from main, but in those 4 tasks, 1st task needs to be completed before I can run other tasks in parallel.

Comment: I will never understand why people use threads when they want sequential execution. *Obviously* you should run the first task inline and then spawn the other three tasks.

Comment: @EJP I need to execute my 4 tasks in a separate flow from main method, and last 3 out of 4 tasks depends on the output of the 1st task.

Comment: Anyone know where to find the answer to this question in terms of Callables rather than Runnables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the new [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) facility.  It might not provide a lot of help with a trivial case such as yours but it offers a lot of flexibility:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.allOf;
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync;

runAsync(() -> doTask1(), executor)
        .thenCompose(v -> allOf(
                runAsync(() -> doTask2(), executor),
                runAsync(() -> doTask3(), executor),
                runAsync(() -> doTask4(), executor)
        ));
```

Where this approach would really shine you is if you needed to pass output of task1 to the dependent tasks.  Suppose that `doTask1` returns a `String` and `doTask2` accepts a `String`.  Now instead of `runAsync` for the first task we should use `supplyAsync`:

```
supplyAsync(() -> doTask1(), executor)
        .thenCompose(resultOf1 -> allOf(
                runAsync(() -> doTask2(resultOf1), executor),
                runAsync(() -> doTask3(), executor),
                runAsync(() -> doTask4(), executor)
        ));
```

Comment: But this approach hold my main method until completion. I need to exit from main without waiting for these 4 tasks to complete.

Comment: In that case, your main method should return `CompletableFuture<Void>` instead of `join`ing.  I edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an `ExecutorService` as well, much like your original approach. All you have to do is to *use* the result of `submit` which allows subsequent tasks to wait for its completion:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
Future<?> task1 = executor.submit(() -> doTask1());
Stream.<Runnable>of(() -> doTask2(), () -> doTask3(), () -> doTask4())
      .forEach(r -> executor.submit(() -> { try {
              task1.get();
              r.run();
          } catch(InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex){}
      }));
executor.shutdown();
```

We have to catch exceptions when waiting for the completion of the first task, but this also opens the opportunity to deliberately skip the next task if the first task fails or gets canceled. Since normally, the dependency between tasks exists because the subsequent tasks need the *result* of the first task, waiting via `get()` is the natural way. As soon as `doTask1()` returns a value, the `submit` invocation above will use `submit(Callable)` rather than `submit(Runnable)` and the returned `Future` will have a generic type reflecting the return type of the method, so the result can be retrieved via its `get()` method.

In order to avoid deadlocks, it least one of the following conditions must be true:

- there are enough threads for all submitted tasks, or
- the queue’s retrieval order is identical to the submission order

In the example, even both apply.

Note that the stream use above is not necessary, a classical loop could do that as well:

```
for(Runnable r: Arrays.<Runnable>asList(() -> doTask2(), () -> doTask3(), () -> doTask4()))
    executor.submit(() -> { try {
            task1.get();
            r.run();
        } catch(InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex){}
    });
```